# What does 'Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100' mean?

Tags: network, safari

We recently migrated our website to a new server and in the process some of our older Macs can no longer access it. All other computers are fine. These devices run MacOS 10.12.6 (I'm not sure about the specific version of Safari, but for the sake of argument let's assume it's of a similar age).  The error logs contain lines such as these:

```
3/17/22, 6:00:19 AM Beginning Log
3/17/22, 6:00:22 AM access to url 'https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog'
3/17/22, 6:00:22 AM access to url 'https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog'
3/17/22, 6:00:23 AM access to url 'https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog'
3/17/22, 8:01:32 AM failure when provising url 'https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog' error 'Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}'
3/17/22, 8:06:32 AM failure when provising url 'https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog' error 'Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=100 "Protocol error" UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://lib.skidmore.edu/#library-catalog, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=100, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}'
```

Some background may help.  The devices use an app whose name escapes me to restrict access to a subset of websites (namely our library's - these are kiosks).  However the URL is unchanged.  We've whitelisted any possible other URL the devices may be hitting by accident, to no avail.  We've also cleared the cache and restarted them multiple times without success, so it seems unlikely they are holding into old DNS settings. Nothing changed on the clients and both old and new servers run Litespeed.

My hypothesis is the new server has some setting turned on which is causing the issue above.  However I've been having trouble finding more information about what the specific error means.  Could anyone shine some light on what, if anything, the error log is trying to tell me other than "I can't access this website"? That would help me pinpoint how to better tune Litespeed (or what else to adjust) in order to fix the problem.

**Update:**  It turns out the error is specific to the kiosk app.  So this question may actually be out of bounds for this website.

**Update 2:** We ended up pointing the kiosks at a different website, thus side-stepping the error.

Comment: A quick google suggests the problem may be to do with: Firewall, AV software, proxy servers, certificates, or the use of HTTP 2.0. Have you tested any/all of these?

Comment: My ability to troubleshoot is limited by not having admin access to the machines.  However we don't run AV software or proxy servers with them and I don't think they have a firewall unless one is built into MacOS.  While I wonder about HTTP 2.0, the old server used Litespeed as well and everything was fine.  Right now my thinking is to just replace the machines as they are old and the kiosk app is unsupported.

Comment: Also the error is apparently specific to the app, something I did not know earlier today (I will update the question shortly).

Comment: The debug lines look like logs from an app you have to ask the app developers what they mean. The app should be reporting a more user friendly message if the app developers are not the ones reviewing the logs.